# AWS Lambda Trigger Enable/Disable Log

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We have a lambda function with **SQS** as trigger. The functions were working fine for a few years up until last week when we saw that the trigger was disabled for some reason.

We had to manually enable the trigger to make it work.

Is there any way to check why or who had disabled this trigger in some sort of a **log**?

Answer (score 2):

AWS provides [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) which stores a log  for every event which happened in your account for the last 90 days.
Triggers are tied to the service which invokes them (SQS in your case), so I suggest searching for SQS events in the CloudTrail logs and also for Lambda modification events.